# how to run rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i installed rails gem on my machine
gem install rails-0.9.2.gem 
nd i got message like Successfully installed rails, version 0.9.2
now try to run a command like rail amit
but nothing happened not even a single message???

Answer (score -1):

Start here :

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project

Answer (score -1):

The command to create a new application is `rails [application-name]`. Did you type `rail amit` instead of `rails amit`?

If it wasn't a typo, run `which rails` to find the rails executable, and make sure you have `rx` access to it.